# T-SQL: An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Arithmetic Overflow for select * from MyTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003-r2

I'm doing a simple query like this:

```
select * from MyTable
```

This results in the following error:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Arithmetic
>   Overflow

I can run `select top 14 * from MyTable` and it works without a problem but on the 15th value the error occurs, `select top 15 * from MyTable` shows Arithmetic Overflow error.

The table consists of columns with data types: `int`, `float` and `smallint`.

I have confirmed that the error does not occur in the `int` or `smallint` columns so it is happening in a `float` column.

Two questions:

- How can this happen in the first place since I'm only selecting existing values?
- How can I find and view the specific value causing the error?

Running `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00` on `Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition with Service Pack 2`.

Update with Design:

```
USE [myDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MyTable]    Script CMte: 12/10/2019 10:35:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [DeliveryYearID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryYear] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VolumeDelivery_H] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Volum__74C75C08]  DEFAULT (0),
    [VolumeDelivery_S] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Volum__75BB8041]  DEFAULT (0),
    [SurchargeSale_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Surch__76AFA47A]  DEFAULT (0),
    [SurchargeAdjust_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Surch__77A3C8B3]  DEFAULT (0.0),
    [SurchargeSale_moving] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Surch__7897ECEC]  DEFAULT (0),
    [SurchargeAdjust_moving] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Surch__798C1125]  DEFAULT (0.0),
    [FixedCharge_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Fixed__7A80355E]  DEFAULT (0),
    [FixedCharge_moving] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__Fixed__7B745997]  DEFAULT (0),
    [OfferedPriceP1_Edit_fast] [float] NOT NULL,
    [OfferedPriceP2_Edit_fast] [float] NOT NULL,
    [OfferedPriceP3_Edit_fast] [float] NOT NULL,
    [OfferedPriceP4_Edit_fast] [float] NOT NULL,
    [OfferedSurcharge_Edit_moving] [float] NOT NULL,
    [movingTak_moving] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__movingT__7C687DD0]  DEFAULT (0),
    [movingTakPremie_moving] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__movingT__7D5CA209]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeDelivery] [float] NOT NULL,
    [C_ChargePerUnit] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Cha__7E50C642]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SurchargeBase] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sur__7F44EA7B]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeSurcharge_moving] [float] NOT NULL,
    [C_VolumeCost] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__00390EB4]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeCostP1] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__012D32ED]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeCostP2] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__02215726]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeCostP3] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__03157B5F]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeCostP4] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__04099F98]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeDeliveryP1] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__04FDC3D1]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeDeliveryP2] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__05F1E80A]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeDeliveryP3] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__06E60C43]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumeDeliveryP4] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__07CM307C]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SurchargUYNrmin_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sur__08CE54B5]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SurchargUYNrminP1_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sur__09C278EE]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SurchargUYNrminP2_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sur__0AB69D27]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SurchargUYNrminP3_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sur__0BAAC160]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SurchargUYNrminP4_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sur__0C9EE599]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_movingSurcharge_moving] [float] NOT NULL,
    [C_EffectSurcharge_moving] [float] NOT NULL,
    [C_BalanceSurcharge_moving] [float] NOT NULL,
    [C_ProfileSurcharge_moving] [float] NOT NULL,
    [C_movingKundPrisTak_moving] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Spo__0D9309D2]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SeparateCost_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sep__0E872E0B]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SeparateCost_moving] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Sep__0F7B5244]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumePrice] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__106F767D]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumePriceP1] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__11639AB6]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumePriceP2] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__1257BEEF]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumePriceP3] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__134BE328]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_VolumePriceP4] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Vol__14400761]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_MonthFirst] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Mon__15342B9A]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_MonthLast] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_Mon__16284FD3]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_SurchargeSaleAdjust_AP] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeSaleAdjust_AP]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_HourlyPercentage] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_HourlyPercentage]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_OffertRisk_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_OffertRisk_fast]  DEFAULT (0.0),
    [C_SurchargeCertificate_fast] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeCertificate_fast]  DEFAULT (0.0),
    [C_TB_Sum] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_TB___23582DBF]  DEFAULT (0),
    [C_TB_PerUnit] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tblSaleOb__C_TB___244C51F8]  DEFAULT (0),
    [SurchargeMarketInvestment_fast] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [SurchargeMarketInvestment_moving] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_StructuralCostSurcharge] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_FASTPRISBAS_P0] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_movingPRISBAS_P0] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_StructuralCostSurcharge_fast] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_StructuralCostSurcharge_moving] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_StructuralCostCoefficient] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Other_Swedish_Storage] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Physical_Profile_Risk] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Transport_Plus_Storage_Included] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Transport_Plus_Storage_Separate] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Transmission_TE_IUP_HYU] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [SellerSurcharge_IUP_HYU] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [AdjustedSurcharge_IUP_HYU] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_BuyOtherPe] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [BuySurcharge_HYU_in_EFR] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [BuySurcharge_EFR_in_HYU] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [Offered_BuySurcharge_HYU] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Profile_Cost_CM_EFR] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Volume_Risk] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_Other_LJR_BDU] [float] NULL,
    [CorrectionValue] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_UYN_Exit_Cost] [float] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0.0)),
    [C_CapacityCost_HYU_Included] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_CapacityCost_HYU_Included]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_CapacityCost_HYU_Separate] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_CapacityCost_HYU_Separate]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP1_Etage_HYU] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP1_Etage_HYU]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP2_Etage_HYU] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP2_Etage_HYU]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP3_Etage_HYU] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP3_Etage_HYU]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP4_Etage_HYU] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP4_Etage_HYU]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP1_Etage_EFR] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP1_Etage_HYU1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP2_Etage_EFR] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP2_Etage_HYU1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP3_Etage_EFR] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP3_Etage_HYU1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_SurchargeP4_Etage_EFR] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_SurchargeP4_Etage_HYU1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_Surcharge_Etage_HYU] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_Surcharge_Etage_HYU]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [C_Surcharge_Etage_EFR] [float] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_C_Surcharge_Etage_EFR]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [MyTable2_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [DeliveryYearID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [MyTable3_MyTable_FK1] FOREIGN KEY([DeliveryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MyTable3] ([DeliveryID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [MyTable3_MyTable_FK1]
```

Update 2:

Found the column causing the error: `[C_SurchargUYNrminP2_fast]`

```
select top 15 [C_SurchargUYNrminP2_fast] from MyTable
```

Update 3:

Tested the query suggested by @LukStorms. Error received:

> Msg 9100, Level 23, State 2, Line 2 Possible index corruption
>   detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB.

```
-- Change col1 to your actual primary key column(s), col2 to the column from the 2570 error, table1 to the table from the CHECKDB output
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
WHERE col2<>0.0 AND (col2 < 2.23E-308 OR col2 > 1.79E+308) AND (col2 < -1.79E+308 OR col2 > -2.23E-308)
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/923247/troubleshooting-dbcc-error-2570-in-sql-server-2005-and-later-versions

Update 4:

Command: `DBCC CHECKTABLE(N'dbo.MyTable') WITH DATA_PURITY`

> Msg 2570, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Page (1:30707), slot 8 in object
>   ID 1330364054, index ID 1, partition ID 72057615345844224, alloc unit
>   ID 72057615349710848 (type "In-row data"). Column
>   "C_SurchargUYNrminP2_fast" value is out of range for data type
>   "float".  Update column to a legal value.

Comment: since there are only 15 rows, can you post sql fiddle

Comment: Does the table have one or more computed columns?

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting that error with this table definition.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Updated question with design, 14 rows work but the 15th does not work. Do you need anything else?

Comment: @EdHarper No, not that I can tell at least. Please see create definitions.

Comment: @GSerg I don't understand it either. Found the column now at least. Any idea how to investigate it further?

Comment: Was the data bulk loaded?  Check [this help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/923247/troubleshooting-dbcc-error-2570-in-sql-server-2005-and-later-versions).

Comment: I had a similar problem when someone somehow managed to store Double.NaN as value in Database Table.

Comment: @LukStorms Don't know, the system has been running since 2006 and the knowledge about these parts of the system are very scarce.

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn How did you find the value?

Comment: That help page has an example for floats. `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
WHERE col2<>0.0 AND (col2 < 2.23E-308 OR col2 > 1.79E+308) AND (col2 < -1.79E+308 OR col2 > -2.23E-308)` Just a bit troubling that your table has so many floats O_o

Comment: @LukStorms Thanks! Unfortunately it returned the error `Msg 9100, Level 23, State 2, Line 2
Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB.`. Will investigate further.

Comment: Try running `DBCC CHECKTABLE(N'dbo.MyTable') WITH DATA_PURITY`. I've seen column value corruption introduced by mal-formed parameter values in old SQL Server versions, before strict TDS checks were introduced.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks! See update for result. Is there anyway that I can view the actual value?

Comment: You can dump the page using [`DBCC PAGE`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/06/10/how-to-use-dbcc-page/). `DBCC TRACEON(3604); --return output to client
DECLARE @db_id int = DB_ID();
DBCC PAGE(1,30707, 1);DBCC TRACEOFF(3604);`. The info might not be particularly useful. To fix it, the easiest method might be to update the problem value to zero since the intended value is lost.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks! Used `printopt 3 – page header plus detailed per-row interpretation` to see the actual value. Got the corresponding primary key this way so the value could be updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @DanGuzman and everyone else in comments.

Found the corrupt values with the command:

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE(N'dbo.MyTable') WITH DATA_PURITY
```

> Msg 2570, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Page (1:30707), slot 8 in object
>   ID 1330364054, index ID 1, partition ID 72057615345844224, alloc unit
>   ID 72057615349710848 (type "In-row data"). Column
>   "C_SurchargUYNrminP2_fast" value is out of range for data type
>   "float". Update column to a legal value.

I could then use `DBCC PAGE` to find the corrupt value and the corresponding primary key. With this help I could update the value.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/06/10/how-to-use-dbcc-page/

```
DBCC TRACEON ( 3604 )
DBCC PAGE ( 'myDB' , 1 , 30707 , 3 )
DBCC TRACEOFF ( 3604 )
```

> Slot 8 Column 1 Offset 0x4 Length 4
>
> DeliveryID = 123
>
> Slot 8 Column 33 Offset 0xf0 Length 8
>
> C_SurchargUYNrminP2_fast = -1.#IND